# WPF application closes when I close Splash Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, splash-screen

I want to add a splash screen to my WPF app in a new thread (because my animated splash screen hangs when the data for Main window is loading). Code:

```
SplashScreenWindow splashScreenWindow = null;
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    splashScreenWindow = new SplashScreenWindow();
    splashScreenWindow.ShowDialog();
});
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();

   data loading...

_mainWindow.Show();
splashScreenWindow.Close();
```

My problem is that the program closes when I close the splash screen.

Comment: You know you can just add an image to your project, set it's Build Action to "Splash Screen" and the framework will take care this for you, right?

Comment: My splash screen isn't an image. It's a window that has an animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar, this works for me.

```
SplashScreenWindow splashScreenWindow = null;
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    splashScreenWindow = new SplashScreenWindow();
    splashScreenWindow.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();

data loading...

_mainWindow.Show();
```

You are calling the close too early, call the splashScreenWindow.Close() from the main window Loaded event.

```
_mainWindow.Loaded += (s,ev) => { 
splashScreenWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(.splashScreenWindow.Close));
};
```

Comment: Next row `_mainWindow.Loaded += (s,ev) => { splashScreenWindow.Close(); }` throw an exception: `System.InvalidOperationException. The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it` I've changed the row to `_mainWindow.Loaded += (s, ev) => { Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _splashScreenWindow.Close()); };`, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: I just edited to add the dispatcher fix. The other thing that I am doing differently is that my main window is registered via the App.xaml StartupUri, I am not calling mainWindow.Show() The splashscreenWindow.close is called from the Window_Loaded event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.Show()` is not a blocking call meaning it will return regardless to the window actually closing, so the application will run out to the end more than likely.

Use `.ShowDialog()`.

Make sure you close the splash screen before calling this.

Comment: I've changed my code to: _splashScreenWindow.Close();
 _mainWindow.ShowDialog();  But It doesn't help me.

Comment: Something else is closing your application outside this code. When calling `.ShowDialog()` it should wait for the window to close. Are you sure you're not terminating elsewhere?